# Getting the cannot callsendredirect() after the response has been committed

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

Again my question related with the same project which i am doing for the report tracking system getting the below error in the tomcat logs after accessing the login page which is redirect towards "userloginmid.jsp".The code as shown below in the same window.

Please provide the solution for the same if possible.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*,java.text.*,java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
<%

  String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

    System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "report_tracking";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String username = "root"; 
    String userPassword = "root";

      java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
      String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    String strDateNew = sdf.format(now) ;


    try {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,username,userPassword);
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      String strQuery = "select * from userregister where username='"+userName+"' and password='"+password+"'"; 
      out.println(strQuery);
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

       if(rs.next())
        {

            int userid=rs.getInt(1);
            String user=rs.getString(2);

            session.setAttribute("userid",userid);
            session.setAttribute("username",user);
            session.setAttribute("intime",strDateNew);

            String queryString = "INSERT INTO admin set userid="+userid+",intime='"+strDateNew+"'";
            int i = st.executeUpdate(queryString);

            if(i>0)
            {
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
            }

        }

        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 %>
```

Comment: Not sufficient details to answer you question. Each question is here is treated as separate entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all said there are lot of `loopholes` in your code.

But the answer to your quesion is

```
sendRedirect requires a return statement
```

So change your lines of code to

`response.sendRedirect( "welcome.jsp"); return;` and

```
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp"); return;
```

Also read [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/legacy/kb/jrun-4-using-sendredirect-requires.html) .

Comment: hey suresh thanks for the suggestion but its not working actually

Comment: means getting the same exception still ?

Comment: yes still getting the same error code in catalina server logs

Comment: In your servlets after all forward request add return req.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(req, resp);return;

i thought the problem solved because you accepted as answer for the above answer( green tick )

Comment: I am 100% sure that you forgot adding return; some where after the forward and redirect check all possibilities

Comment: @suresh ...required more help from your side for the further process in this project

Comment: for sure :) keep asking questions

Comment: i want to setup a new page which is creating new case for the specific client(IssueID,Date,Problem submit by,Problem description)+Buttons(Save,Delete,Exit,Cancel) can anyone provide me any good example for that.

Comment: you have to ask for a new question for that.Some one can help you out .you want to register an user right ??http://www.javatpoint.com/registration-form-in-jsp

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

First, the explanation of your stated problem, redirecting after committing a response:

When the HTTP headers are already sent to the client (read about the HTTP protocol if you don't know it yet), they are out and cannot be pulled back. You're coding your sample in a jsp, which is the VIEW part of your architecture - and at least between the "page import" and the code part there's a newline which might trigger the server to flush its buffers to the client. Once that's done, the HTTP headers are gone and you cannot redirect any more.

Workaround: Don't implement this routine in a jsp, but in a servlet (or use a decent framework that handles this problem for you. Any of the current will suffice).

Now about some of the problems that your code has:

- Please read about [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/). Think of someone posting
  usernames like `someone';` `someone' OR '0' = '0` or similar (just
  making them up as I go)
- Once you get your connection and run in to any error, you won't clean
  up the connection (e.g. you will leak connections on any exception)
- You seem to be storing clear text passwords. Definitely a no-go as
  soon as someone else than you will have an account